# Am I doomed due to thoughts of disbelief, and what can I do about them?

Tags: evil-thoughts

I have no doubt in religion Islam. I believe it's true.

But I am worried because I have some serious waswas or thoughts of disbelief. I am wondering if I am doomed or not. I don't want to goto hell fire forever.
I don't want to be like those people who are munafiq or hypocrites and I don't want to be like those people who say they believe but they disbelieve.

I am scared of hell fire. I love Allah and I know he is the creator and Prophet Muhammad (S.A.W) is the last messenger.

I don't know what to do. I know I should not utter thoughts at all. Anything which crosses our mind is forgiven. I hope I don't hold the thoughts as convictions.

What should I do? I am worried if I am a true Muslim or not.

Comment: What is it that makes you worry? It is bot clear what you are asking..

Comment: It's the thoughts of disbelief that make me worried.

Comment: What kind of thoughts?

Comment: They are random thoughts of disbelief. I don't want to utter them cause I heard it's haram to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure is your disturbed mind which is being prayed on by the Satan (you may call it --WASWASA) Just shrug it off and keep busy, praying and in "ZIKR" of ---"AStagfar-Ullah"---, as much as possible. Insha-Allah things would change for the better. Whenever your mind strays, concenterate on your conviction of your belief in Islam and Allah. Remind Yourself often, that you are a devout Muslim. Thanks